# Why is the root route still returning the default Rails page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, ruby-on-rails-4

When I typed the code below in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def hello
    render html: "hello, world!"
  end
end
```

and the code below in `config/routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'application#hello'
end
```

The root route still returns the default Rails page while I was expecting it would return "hello, world!". Please help me with this small issue.

Comment: Did you try in a different browser? It might be a caching issue. Also try removing `public/index.html` to be sure.

Comment: Yes, I did save everything. However, when I rebooted my laptop, suddenly the page displays a page saying the following:

Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/"

Rails.root: /home/Yassine/workspace/hello_app

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Routes

Routes match in priority from top to bottom

You don't have any routes defined!

Please add some routes in config/routes.rb.
For more information about routes, please see the Rails guide Rails Routing from the Outside In.
Helper HTTP Verb Path Controller#Action
Path / Url  
Path Match
Request

Comment: Try running rake routes

Answer (score 0):

I just built a test app and used your code above...it worked great!  I went to `http://localhost:3000` and successfully got the "hello, world!" message.

What version of rails are you using?

What happens when you run `rake routes` (or `rails routes` if you're on 5+) from the command line?  Mine looks like this:

```
$ rake routes
Prefix Verb URI Pattern Controller#Action
root GET  /           application#hello
```

Note - you might need to restart your rails server depending on how you have everything set up but if your server is running on your laptop, the reboot should have handled that.